# MINT Freezes on boot after load the system

Tags: linux-mint, boot, dual-boot

I'm trying to install Linux Mint on my notebook and still geting a strange problem.

After i boot on Mint, and the system started after like 2 minutes it just freeze first freeze the system and then the mouse and keyboard.

I'm trying to install Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon, so i search on mint website and found something like:

```
Solving freezes with NVIDIA GeForce GPUs
The open-source drivers present in Linux Mint do not support some of the NVIDIA cards very well. You might experience black screens, freezes or kernel panics.

The best way to solve the issue is to keep trying, until it eventually works. Once the system is installed:

Run the Driver Manager
Choose the NVIDIA drivers and wait for them to be installed
Reboot the computer
With these drivers the system should now be stable.

If you're using an Optimus card, you've nothing more to do. Upon reboot, a systray icon should show up indicating which GPU is currently active. Click on it to switch GPUs.

Note: If no matter how many times you try, you cannot boot or install with the open-source drivers, try one of the following solutions:

At the boot menu of the live DVD/USB, press Tab to edit the boot arguments and add "nomodeset" at the end of the line.
Remove "quiet splash --" from that same line.
Append "nouveau.noaccel=1" at the end of the line.
```

I've tryed the 'nomdeset' and remove 'quiet splash --' and put the 'nouveau.noacell=1' but nothing work. I just get to don't load the visual screen just command line, command line works fine. But how i install the system properly from command line?
I have NVIDIA GeForce GTX 770M and Intel HD Graphics 4600, have someway to change my GPU to the Intel just until i install and download the correct drive from nvidia?
Somebody has a solution?